# Matching line without and with lower-case letters

Tags: regex

I want to match two consecutive lines, with the first line having no lower-case letter and the second having lower-case letter(s), e.g.

```
("3.2 A MEMORY ABSTRACTION: ADDRESS SPACES 177" "#205")
("3.3.1 Paging 187" "#215")
```

Why would the Regex `^(?!.*[:lower:]).*$\n^(.*[:lower:]).*$` match each of the following two-line examples?

```
("1.3.3 Disks 24" "#52")
("1.3.4 Tapes 25" "#53")

("1.5.4 Input/Output 41" "#69")
("1.5.5 Protection 42" "#70")

("3.1 NO MEMORY ABSTRACTION 174" "#202")
("3.2 A MEMORY ABSTRACTION: ADDRESS SPACES 177" "#205")

("3.3.1 Paging 187" "#215")
("3.3.2 Page Tables 191" "#219")
```

Thanks and regards!

---

ADDED:

For a example such as:

```
("3.1 NO MEMORY ABSTRACTION 174" "#202")
("3.2 A MEMORY ABSTRACTION: ADDRESS SPACES 177" "#205")
("3.3.1 Paging 187" "#215")
("3.3.2 Page Tables 191" "#219")
```

How shall I match only the middle two lines not the first three lines or all the four lines?

Answer (score 2):

Using [Rubular](http://rubular.com/), we can see [what's matched by your initial expression](http://rubular.com/r/gR91qqJxII), and then, by adding a few excess capturing groups, [see why it matches](http://rubular.com/r/v1LUswt00q).

Essentially, the negative look-ahead followed by `.*` will match anything. If you merely want to check that the first line has no lower-case letters, check that explicitly, e.g.

```
^(?:[^a-z]+)$
```

Finally, I'd assuming you want the entire second line, you can do this for the second part:

```
^(.*?(?=[:lower:]).*?)$
```

Or to match your inital version:

```
^(.*?(?=[:lower:])).*?$
```

The reluctant qualifiers (`*?`) seemed to be necessary to avoid matching across lines.

The final version I ended up with, thus, is:

```
^(?:[^a-z]+)$\n^(.*?(?=[:lower:]).*?)$
```

This can be seen in action with your test data [here](http://rubular.com/r/xtoVArPzoS). It only captures the line `("3.2 A MEMORY ABSTRACTION: ADDRESS SPACES 177" "#205")`.

Obviously, the regex I've used might be quite specific to Ruby, so testing with your regex engine may be somewhat different. There are many easily Google-able online regex tests, I just picked on Rubular since it does a wonderful job of highlighting what is being matched.

Incidentally, if you're using Python, the [Python Regex Tool](http://www.pythonregex.com/) is very helpful for online testing of Python regexes (and it works with the final version I gave above), though I find the output visually less helpful in trouble-shooting.

---

After thinking about it a little more, Alan Moore's point about `[[:lower:]]` is spot on, as is his point about how the data would match. Looking back at what I wrote, I got a little too involved in breaking-down the regex and missed something about the problem as described. If you modify the regex I gave above to:

```
^(?:[^[:lower:]]+)$\n^(.*?(?=[[:lower:]]).*?)$
```

It matches only the line `("3.3.1 Paging 187" "#215")`, which is the only line with lowercase letters following a line with no lowercase letters, as [can be seen here](http://rubular.com/r/XDqzubd4ll). Placing a capturing group in Alan's expression, yielding `^(?!.*[[:lower:]]).+\n((?=.*[[:lower:]]).*)$` [likewise captures the same text](http://rubular.com/r/emZqjUyuYO), though what, exactly, is matched is different.

I still don't have a good solution for matching multiple lines.

Comment: Thanks! (1) If there are more than two lines, where all except the last line have no lower-case letters, all these lines will be a match to your Regex. But I just want to match two-line cases. How shall it be modified? (2)  I wonder why "what you were testing was that the second character wasn't lower-case"?

Comment: @Tim: I'll have to give #1 some thought. As for #2, `^(?!.*[:lower:]).*`, the `.*` at the end of that segment is going to greedily match any character. The negative look-ahead is just going to apply to the start of the string. After testing it using the tools mentioned above, it actually seems to match anything (see [here](http://rubular.com/r/aST3J3R2oW)). I've edited the answer accordingly.

Comment: @Tim: Do you have an example of the more than two line case? I can't replicate it. See [this example](http://rubular.com/r/rMPjhx7BTH)

Comment: Thanks! (1) In your linked example, how shall I match only the middle two lines not the first three lines or all the four lines? (2) In the link, can the matched result be shown?

Answer (score 2):

To use a POSIX "character class" like `[:lower:]`, you have to enclose it in another set of square brackets, like this: `[[:lower:]]`.  (According to POSIX, the outer set of brackets form a *bracket expression* and `[:lower:]` is a *character class*, but to everyone else the outer brackets define a *character class* and the inner `[:lower:]` is obsolete.)

Another problem with your regex is that the first part is not required to consume any characters; everything is optional.  That means your match can start on the blank line, and I don't think you want that.  Changing the second `.*` to `.+` fixes that, but it's just a quick patch.

This regex seems to match your specification:

```
^(?!.*[[:lower:]]).+\n(?=.*[[:lower:]]).*$
```

But I'm a little puzzled, because there's nothing in your sample data that matches.  Is there supposed to be?

Comment: Thanks! I just updated my post. The first example is supposed to be a match.